# Can't link C++ methods in same source file using Gradle

Tags: c++, macos, gradle, linker

I'm trying to use Gradle (5.6.2) to build a basic C++ library, and cannot figure out what is going wrong here.  I started out using Gradle init to create the basic structure... here's my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    // Apply the cpp-library plugin to add support for building C++ libraries
    id 'cpp-library'

    // Apply the cpp-unit-test plugin to add support for building and running C++ test executables
    id 'cpp-unit-test'
}

// Set the target operating system and architecture for this library
library {
    targetMachines.add(machines.macOS.x86_64)
    dependencies {
        implementation files('/usr/local/lib/libjsoncpp.a') // used by classA
    }
}

tasks.withType(CppCompile).configureEach {
    compilerArgs.add "-std=c++11"
    compilerArgs.add "-w"
}
```

The source tree looks like this:

```
src/main/cpp -> classA.cpp classB.cpp classB.hpp hello.cpp
src/main/public -> classA.hpp cppd.h cpplib.h
src/test/cpp -> classATest.cpp hello_test.cpp
```

hello.cpp, cppd.h, cpplib.h, and hello_test.cpp all came from the 'gradle init' and aren't actually used.

classA calls a few methods in classB.  classB only depends on standard libraries.

classB has a public method classB::method1() that calls two private methods classB::method2() and classB::method3()

When I build, I get a linker error that it can't find classB::method2() or classB::method3().  I checked the method signatures and they all match up (same number and type of arguments in classB.hpp, classB.cpp, and in the linker error message).

I've scoured the Gradle documentation and Googled everything I can think of, tried several variations on the build.gradle file, and... I don't understand why the linker can't find methods in the same CPP file??

Building with Clang 11.0 on MacOS 10.14.6 in case it matters...

Also for reference, here's the relevant bits of the header file:

```
class classB {
public:
  method1();
private:
  string& method2(const string& s, bool b);
  int method3(uint16_t* b, const string& s);
}
```

And the methods from the cpp file:

```
string& method2(const string& s, bool b) {
 // blah
}

int method3(uint16_t* b, const string& s) {
  // blah
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OH MY GOODNESS!  Just... Nevermind.  You know how sometimes posting the question itself is enough to make the problem obvious?

For the record, of course what's missing is the class identifyer-thing (sorry, can't recall the term, I'm coming back from Java) on the front of the method names in the CPP file.  They should be:

```
string& classB::method2(const string& s, bool b) {
 // blah
}

int classB::method3(uint16_t* b, const string& s) {
  // blah
}
```

Without the class identifyer-things, the linker doesn't realize they are member functions, and doesn't make the connection.